# Flask Middleware with both Request and Response

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

I want to create a middleware function in Flask that logs details from the request *and* the response. The middleware should run after the Response is created, but before it is sent back. I want to log:

1. The request's HTTP method (`GET`, `POST`, or `PUT`)
2. The request endpoint
3. The response HTTP status code, *including 500 responses*. So, if an exception is raised in the view function, I want to record the resulting 500 Response before the Flask internals send it off.

Some options I've found (that don't quite work for me):

1. The [`before_request`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.before_request) and [`after_request`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.after_request) decorators. If I could access the request data in `after_request`, my problems still won't be solved, because according to the documentation

> If a function raises an exception, any remaining `after_request` functions will not be called.

2. [Deferred Request Callbacks](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/deferredcallbacks/) - there is an [`after_this_request`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.after_this_request) decorator described on this page, which decorates an arbitrary function (defined inside the current view function) and registers it to run after the current request. Since the arbitrary function can have info from both the request and response in it, it partially solves my problem. The catch is that I would have to add such a decorated function to every view function; a situation I would very much like to avoid.

> ```
> @app.route('/')
> def index():
>     @after_this_request
>     def add_header(response):
>         response.headers['X-Foo'] = 'Parachute'
>         return response
>     return 'Hello World!'
> ```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first answer is very hacky. There's actually a much better way to achieve the same result by making use of the [`g object`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.g) in Flask. It is useful for storing information globally during a single request. From [the documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/appcontext/#storing-data):

> The g name stands for “global”, but that is referring to the data being global within a context. The data on g is lost after the context ends, and it is not an appropriate place to store data between requests. Use the session or a database to store data across requests.

This is how you would use it:

```
@app.before_request
def gather_request_data():
    g.method = request.method
    g.url = request.url

@app.after_request
def log_details(response: Response):
    g.status = response.status

    logger.info(f'method: {g.method}\n url: {g.url}\n status: {g.status}')

    return response
```

1. Gather whatever request information you want in the function decorated with `@app.before_request` and store it in the `g` object.
2. Access whatever you want from the response in the function decorated with `@app.after_request`. You can still refer to the information you stored in the `g` object from step 1. Note that you'll have to return the response at the end of this function.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `flask-http-middleware` for it [link](https://pypi.org/project/flask-http-middleware/)

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_http_middleware import MiddlewareManager, BaseHTTPMiddleware

app = Flask(__name__)

class MetricsMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    def dispatch(self, request, call_next):
        url = request.url
        response = call_next(request)
        response.headers.add("x-url", url)
        return response

app.wsgi_app = MiddlewareManager(app)
app.wsgi_app.add_middleware(MetricsMiddleware)

@app.get("/health")
def health():
    return {"message":"I'm healthy"}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Every time you make request, it will pass the middleware

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the answer was staring me in the face the whole time, on the page on [Deferred Request Callbacks](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/deferredcallbacks/).

The trick is to register a function to run after the current request using `after_this_request` *from inside the `before_request` callback*. This is the code snippet of what worked for me:

```
@app.before_request
def log_details():
    method = request.method
    url = request.url

    @after_this_request
    def log_details_callback(response: Response):
        logger.info(f'method: {method}\n url: {url}\n status: {response.status}')
```

These are the steps:

1. Get the required details from the response in the `before_request` callback and store them in some variables.
2. Then access what you want of the response in the function you decorate with `after_this_request`, along with the variables you stored the request details in earlier.